# disabled zooming when scrolling the mouse in the tooltip of scatter plot highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a scatter plot highcharts in my page, it renders very well. The problem is when I scroll the mouse within the tooltip area the chart zooming functionality is executing. I need to disabled this one. But I don't want totally to disabled the zooming of the chart since the requirements stated that it needs the chart to zoom in, to look into the dots information when there are overlapping dots. Any help on this please? Or any one has an idea how to find the zoomtype property manually using javascript? I try it to find using firebug but no to avail.

//Code sample

```
var data = [
  [1, 1],
  [2, 2],
  [3, 3],
  [4, 4]
];
var chartingOptions = {
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    zoomType: 'xy'
  },
  tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    shared:false,
    formatter: function() { return '<div style="height:100px;width:200px;overflow:auto"><table><tr><td>sdsd</td></tr><tr><td>sdsd</td></tr><tr><td>sdsd</td></tr><tr><td>sdsd</td></tr><tr><td>sdsd</td></tr><tr><td>sdsd</td></tr><tr><td>sdsd</td></tr></table>'}
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'scatter',
    name: 'serie',
    data: data
  }]
};

chartingOptions = $.extend({}, jugalsLib.getBasicChartOptions(), chartingOptions);
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartingOptions);
var $tooltip = $(chart.tooltip.label.element);
$tooltip.mouseup(function (e) {
  chart.tracker.selectionMarker = chart.tracker.selectionMarker.destroy();
});
```

Comment: Can you give us a jsFiddle? What do you mean by scrolling mouse within tooltip?

Comment: Now I get it, but a jsFiddle would be still be handy?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the mouseup event on the tooltip element and destroy the zoom selection element in this handler. Highcharts uses this selection element to decide if zooming is needed or not. This will trick highcharts to believe that nothing has been selected.

## Code

```
var $tooltip = $(chart.tooltip.label.element);
$tooltip.mouseup(function (e) {
  chart.tracker.selectionMarker = chart.tracker.selectionMarker.destroy();
});
```

There may be some side effects to this, like, if you actually were zooming and your zoom selection happened to end on the tooltip, it won't zoom. This may be acceptable, if not you can find a way to workaround that too, by having some more checks in the above handler to see if its actually zooming or something like that.

## Demo

**[Handling mouse events in tooltip | Highchart & Highstock @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/A6aJW/)**

//Code sample

```
var data = [
  [1, 1],
  [2, 2],
  [3, 3],
  [4, 4]
];
var chartingOptions = {
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    zoomType: 'xy'
  },
  tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    shared:false,
    formatter: function() { return '<div style="height:100px;width:200px;overflow:auto"><table><tr><td>sdsd</td></tr><tr><td>sdsd</td></tr><tr><td>sdsd</td></tr><tr><td>sdsd</td></tr><tr><td>sdsd</td></tr><tr><td>sdsd</td></tr><tr><td>sdsd</td></tr></table>'}
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'scatter',
    name: 'serie',
    data: data
  }]
};

chartingOptions = $.extend({}, jugalsLib.getBasicChartOptions(), chartingOptions);
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartingOptions);
var $tooltip = $(chart.tooltip.label.element);
$tooltip.mouseup(function (e) {
  chart.tracker.selectionMarker = chart.tracker.selectionMarker.destroy();
});
```

Comment: Hi Jugal, I try your solution but no to avail,I try to put the codes in jsFiddle but I am encountering some errors. I forgot to tell you that the tooltip is a custom html not a predefined tooltip. Meaning I created a formatter function in the tooltip set up.

Comment: Hi Jugal, please see the codes added above, that is the sample codes. Using that code you can replicate the issue that I've mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this one. I just add a `mousedown="event.cancelBubble=true"` event in the div element and it WORKS!